# Java 8 LocalDateTime is parsing invalid datetime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I wanted to validate datetime in client side so I wrote the following code. But instead of getting an exception I am getting a proper datetime object for 31st of February date string, which is clearly an invalid date.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy";
        String dateString = "11:30:59 02/31/2015";
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat, Locale.US);
        try {
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Throw invalid date message
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** : 2015-02-28T11:30:59

Does anyone know why `LocalDateTime` is parsing this datetime instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: why are you waiting for an exception?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, presumably because 31 Feb. doesn't exist.

Comment: But formatter does not know about that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does 02/29/2015 (which also doesn't exist) behave as expected?

Comment: @Satya: What makes you think that? Something clearly knows that date doesn't exist, as it's converting it to the 28th...

Comment: @JonSkeet My apologies for misleading you earlier, the problem was not the missing milliseconds. It was in fact the missing Era. It still requires a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` but with a default for the Era, not for milliseconds. If you want to edit & undelete your answer, feel free.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Thanks, will do. Still "urgh".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You just need a strict [`ResolverStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html).

> Parsing a text string occurs in two phases. Phase 1 is a basic text parse according to the fields added to the builder. Phase 2 resolves the parsed field-value pairs into date and/or time objects. This style is used to control how phase 2, resolving, happens.

Sample code - where `withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` is the important change, along with the use of `uuuu` rather than `yyyy` (where `uuuu` is "year" and "yyyy" is "year of era", and therefore ambiguous):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/uuuu";
        String dateString = "11:30:59 02/31/2015";
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern(dateFormat, Locale.US)
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        try {
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // Throw invalid date message
            System.out.println("Exception was thrown");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the yyyy to uuuu in format string then there is no need to mess with ERA

Answer (score 11):

The Java 8 DateTimeFormatter uses yyyy to mean YEAR_OF_ERA, and uuuu to mean YEAR.  You need to modify your pattern string as follows:

```
String dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/uuuu";
```

The DateTimeFormatter defaults to using the SMART resolver style, but you want it to use the STRICT resolver style.  Modify your dateTimeFormatter initialization code as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat, Locale.US)
                                                       .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not rounding down.  February has never had 31 days, and it is impossible to use a validating date / time object to represent a day that doesn't exist.

As a result, it takes the invalid input and gives you the best approximation to the correct date (the last date of February that year).

`SimpleDateFormat` inherits from `DateFormat` which has a `setLenient(boolean value)` method on it.  I would expect that if you called `setLenient(true)` prior to parsing, it would probably complain more, [as detailed in the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)).

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(df.parse("11:30:59 02/29/2015"));
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

I found one solution to recognize date as a valid date with [DateFormat.setLenient(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)). If you try to parse any invalid date it will throws parse exception.

**Edit:**

`Java 8`, but this will raise exception if a month is not between `1` and `12`, if a day is more than `32`. Exactly not working. But for month its working.

```
try {
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy").parse("11:30:59 02/32/2015");
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
```

**Output:**

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11:30:59 02/32/2015' could not be
 parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't work with Java 8 `LocalDateTime`. I am looking for a solution with Java8 LocalDateTime

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime.parse will only throw an error if the String passed in contains invalid characters, a number of days exceeding 31 or a month exceeding 12.

For example, if you modified your code as such:

```
String dateString = "11:30:59 0zz2/31/2015";
```

an exception would be thrown caused by the invalid 'zz' characters within your given date. As to why it's 'rounding-down' the date so to speak, that I don't know.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-