# Java date validation joda time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Is there anyway to validate if a given date(yyyy-MM-dd) is a valid date?
It should handle leap year too. eg(2015-02-29) should be invalid.
I'm retrieving the date as a string and putting it into a joda DateTime object.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java, more specifically @tardate response

Comment: are you using java 8?

Comment: @Satya i'm using java 7

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823368/java-8-localdatetime-is-parsing-invalid-date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you, I think (if you want to keep it simple).
You have to do `setLenient(false)` on a `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
public static boolean validateDate(String dateString){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        sdf.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 15):

The previous responses should be fine, but given that the OP **specifically asked for a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) version**, this alternative will also work:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    String testDateOk = "2015-02-25"; // Normal date, no leap year
    String testDateOk2 = "2016-02-29"; // Edge-case for leap year
    String testDateWrong = "2017-02-29"; // Wrong date in a non-leap year
    String testDateInvalid = "2016-14-29"; // plain wrong date

    assertTrue(isValidDate(testDateOk));
    assertTrue(isValidDate(testDateOk2));
    assertFalse(isValidDate(testDateWrong));
    assertFalse(isValidDate(testDateInvalid));
}

boolean isValidDate(String dateToValidate){
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    try {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
        fmt.parseDateTime(dateToValidate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Would be better to catch `IllegalArgumentException` rather than any old exception.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use SimpleDateFormat

```
public boolean valiDate(String dateString){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You were missing the `setLenient(false)` in the original answer. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
try {  … java.time.LocalDate.parse( input ) … } 
catch ( java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e ) { … }
```

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2015-02-29" ) ;
```

To detect invalid inputs, trap for a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
String input = "2015-02-29";
try
{
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input );
    System.out.println( "ld.toString():  " + ld ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    // … handle exception
    System.out.println( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
}
```

> Text '2015-02-29' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2015' is not a leap year

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).