# Joda Datetime , unable to validate the year format

Tags: scala, datetime

I am using Joda DateTime function in scala to validate the year format
as follows

```
def isValidDateType(value: String, Date_format: String): Unit = {
    val fmt = DateTimeFormat forPattern Date_format
    val output = fmt parseDateTime value
    println(output)
}

isValidDateType("20156-06-06","yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Output : 20156-06-06T00:00:00.000+05:30

```
isValidDateType("201-06-06","yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Output: 0201-06-06T00:00:00.000+05:53:28

Is there any way to validate this year format ?

Comment: What does this have to do with spark ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java date validation joda time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082641/java-date-validation-joda-time)

Comment: I am validating spark datetype using scala code

Comment: it's still has nothing to do with spark. I don't any spark reference in your code. This is just scala and joda

Comment: The year 20,156 and 201 are in principle both valid values for years. Just because you have `yyyy` in your pattern doesn't mean that the year has to be exactly 4 digits. If you require this, write code that checks if there are exactly 4 digits before the first `-`.