# JAVA and JODA Date parsing doesn't throw exception even when format is wrong

Tags: java, jodatime

I am expecting an exception to be thrown for following code and input:

```
SimpleDateFormat getDateTimeFormat(String requiredFormat)
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat);
    //this will make sure that if parsing fails exception is thrown
    dateTimeFormat.setLenient(false);
    return dateTimeFormat;
}
Date date = getDateTimeFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").parse(estimatedDeliveryDttm);
```

Input: 10/25/16 17:46

I am expecting a parsing exception since year is not given as 'yyyy', but I am getting year as '0016' which I do not want.
I cann't use JAVA 8. I already tried JAVA 7 (including parsing position approach) and JODA Date Time API.

Comment: @nbrooks Yes I want exception to be thrown so that I can show error to my user. FYI I also tried parsing position approach as well

Comment: Duplicate. Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082641/java-date-validation-joda-time

Comment: @Azathoth Thanks for your time, but that question is little peculiar as compared to the one mentioned by you. Here I am asking why it is not throwing exception despite passing only 2 digits for year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadocs of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> **Year**: If the formatter's Calendar is the Gregorian calendar, the
> following rules are applied.
>
> For formatting, if the number of pattern
> letters is 2, the year is truncated to 2 digits; otherwise it is
> interpreted as a number.
>
> **For parsing, if the number of pattern letters
> is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the
> number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses
> to Jan 11, 12 A.D.**
>
> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y"
> or "yy"),SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year
> relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within
> 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat
> instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a
> SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string
> "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string
> "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only
> strings consisting of exactly two digits, as defined by
> Character.isDigit(char), will be parsed into the default century. Any
> other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more
> digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for
> example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003"
> are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan 2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

See the bold point above which explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Could you please suggest a way by which we can enforce this without using JAVA 8

Comment: I do not think that it will be possible using Standard Date-Time API prior to java 8. One way you can enforce this by putting a custom logic, If you know the format then you can use regex to match your incoming date against the format. And if that is not matched then throw an exception