# Spring Boot parses invalid dates from request

Tags: java, datetime, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I need solution for this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823368/java-8-localdatetime-is-parsing-invalid-date) within Spring Boot (or Jackson) context.

Not to convert invalid dates: 31.2.2018 -> 28.2.2018
But to throw Exception.

I would like to avoid writing custom serializer/formatter for dates in this case and to use out of the box solution (something like Jackson annotation or annotation attribute). Is there such?

**Code:**

Controller has endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
public Events getAllEvents(@RequestBody EventRequest eventRequest) {}
```

And EventRequest DTO looks like this:

```
public class EventRequest {
    private LocalDateTime eventDate;

    @JsonCreator
    public EventRequest(@JsonProperty(...) @JsonFormat(pattern=...) eventDate){
        this.eventDate = eventDate; // 31.2.2018
        // Don't want to 31.2.2018 -> 28.2.2018 
        // but to THROW EXCEPTION
    }
}
```