Java date-time API - I want invalid 20240230 back as output 20240230, but instead get 28-Feb-2024
    String valueDate(String valueDate_yyyyMMdd) {
        final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_YYYYMMDD = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
        try {
            final LocalDate valueDate = LocalDate.parse(StringUtils.trim(valueDate_yyyyMMdd), DATE_FORMATTER_YYYYMMDD);
            return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(valueDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("failed to convert {} into ddMMMyyyy format", valueDate_yyyyMMdd, e);
            return valueDate_yyyyMMdd;
        }
    }

When I input an invalid date, for example, I hope the method can return the value I input instead of changing it to a valid date.
For example, in the method above, if I pass 20240230 to it, the result is 28-Feb-2024. The "28" is unexpected. What is expected? Because 20240230 is an invalid date, the when parsing it, an exception should be thrown and then catch cluase is executed, so finally the input is returned.
I went through this document Java 8 LocalDateTime is parsing invalid datetime and imporve my code:
    String valueDate(String valueDate_yyyyMMdd) {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_YYYYMMDD = DateTimeFormatter
                    .ofPattern("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US)
                    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
            final LocalDate valueDate = LocalDate.parse(StringUtils.trim(valueDate_yyyyMMdd), DATE_FORMATTER_YYYYMMDD);
            return  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(valueDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("failed to convert {} into ddMMMyyyy format", valueDate_yyyyMMdd, e);
            return valueDate_yyyyMMdd;
        }
    }

But this time, it cannot handle 20230101. An excpetion is thrown:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20230101' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2023, DayOfMonth=1, MonthOfYear=1},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed


Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823368/java-8-localdatetime-is-parsing-invalid-datetime

You want the method to return the same string you passed in?

I think the OP is asking why Feb 30 is considered as a valid date. The link @Marvin provided answers that question. This question should've been closed as a dup, not as needing more details.

Hi @Marvin Thanks! I went though the answer you shared and improved my code, but it doesn't work, could you please help to take a look at my update?

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103603/issue-with-datetimeparseexception-when-using-strict-resolver-style

Many thanks @Marvin It works!

Instead of your formatter, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"), use the built-in DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE. That should solve it (I haven‘t tested).

Curious, for what purpose do you want the same string back in case it is not a valid date in the valid format? Sounds a bit odd to me, but I guess you‘ve got a reason.

tl;dr
Read the documentation.

The default ResolverStyle.SMART tolerates and adjusts faulty inputs.
To reject invalid inputs, use ResolverStyle.STRICT.

DateTimeFormatter
    .BASIC_ISO_DATE                              // Formatter predefined as a constant.
    .withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT )   // Change from default of SMART to STRICT. 

ResolverStyle.SMART
You said:

if I pass 20240230 to it, the result is 28-Feb-2024.

That is a feature, not a bug. As stated in the documentation, by default LocalDate.parse uses ResolverStyle enum object SMART. To quote the JavaDoc for SMART:

converting any value beyond the last valid day-of-month to be the last valid day-of-month.

DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE
You said:

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")

For that pattern, use the predefined constant BASIC_ISO_DATE. The word “basic” is a technical term from ISO 8601 standard.
ResolverStyle.STRICT
You said:

exception should be thrown and then catch cluase is executed

For that behavior, change the ResolverStyle to STRICT. To quote its Javadoc:

ensure that all parsed values are within the outer range of valid values

try
{
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT ) ;
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    … handle faulty input
}

Full example
Here is complete example for both your inputs, valid and invalid.
try
{
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT ) ;
    
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20230101" , f ) ;   // Valid.
    System.out.println( ld ) ;
    
    LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.parse( "20240230" , f ) ;  // Invalid.
    System.out.println( ld ) ;
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    System.out.println( e );
}

See this code run at Ideone.com.

2023-01-01
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20240230' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'


The answer we all wanted. BASIC_ISO_DATE already has strict resolver style, so no need to set it. From the docs: “ It has no override zone and uses the STRICT resolver style.”
